# Deleting polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have implemented a favoriting system for my rails app by following [this great article](http://schmidt-happens.com/articles/2014/06/04/favoriting-system-in-rails.html).

Here is my set up:

---

favorite.rb

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true
end
```

---

project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :favorites, as: :favorited
    has_many :fans, through: :favorites, source: :user
```

---

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listings
  has_many :projects
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :favorite_listings, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Listing'
  has_many :favorite_projects, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Project'
```

---

favorite_projects_controller.rb

```
class FavoriteProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project
  # before_action :correct_user
  # before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    if Favorite.create(favorited: @project, user: current_user)
      redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project has been favorited'
    else
      redirect_to @project, alert: 'Something went wrong...*sad panda*'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Favorite.where(favorited_id: @project.id, user_id: current_user.id).first.destroy
    redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project is no longer in favorites'
  end

  private

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id] || params[:id])
  end
end
```

---

Here is the problem.

I had some favorited projects.

I used `Project.delete_all` to delete my projects while certain projects were still "favorited" but now I get an error:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `favorite_projects' for nil:NilClass):
```

I'm sure If I had "unfavorited" all those projects before deleting them, this error would not come up.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: That line doesn't look like it's referenced in any of the code here.

Comment: tadman, as mmichael says below, I have orphaned my favorite records. I followed the article but I can't wrap my head fully around the polymorphic associations cocnept. I am not sure how to remove favorite_projetcs from my records now that they are orphaned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Rails API docs on `delete_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete_all):

> Deletes the records matching conditions without instantiating the records first, and hence not calling the destroy method nor invoking callbacks. This is a single SQL DELETE statement that goes straight to the database, much more efficient than destroy_all. **Be careful with relations though, in particular :dependent rules defined on associations are not honored. Returns the number of rows affected.**

I bolded the relevant text; and further in the docs:

> If you need to destroy dependent associations or call your before_* or after_destroy callbacks, use the destroy_all method instead.

In summary, you now have orphaned `Favorite` records. I would fire up `rails c` and destroy the orphaned records and be mindful next time you run any `delete` functions.

Comment: Do you think `Favorite.delete_all` would be appropriate here then?

Comment: You can definitely do that so long as you don't mind destroying all your `Favorite` records.

Comment: By the way, if you'd like to only destroy your orphaned records, you could run: `Favorite.where(favorited_type: 'Project').delete_all`. Take a look at [the Rails docs on polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), and note the two database columns `_id` and `_type` (in your case: `favorited_id` and `favorited_type`).

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to set the dependent option.

```
has_many :favorites, as: :favorited, dependent: :destroy
```

Set this on any associations where it doesn't make sense to leave the objects in the db.

You won't need to set it on the `through` has_many associations.

Comment: Just keep in mind that `delete` and `delete_all` will ignore `dependent: :destroy` :)